# MySQL Create Tables Based On Values From A Different Table

Tags: php, mysql, database

What is the proper way to automatically create new tables based on values in another table? For instance, If table A has a column named city that contains different city values then I would need to create a new table based on each different city. Then all records with the respective city needs to be inserted into it's respective table. Also, if the city contains a space in the name it needs to be replaced with a an underscore. How could the same be done in MySQL?

In MS ACCESS I could accomplish this by:

1. Using A Select And Replace Query Named SELREP

   ```
   SELECT table_A.column1, table_A.column2, table_A.city, Replace([city]," ","_") AS table_name_column FROM table_A;
   ```
2. Create a Public Function MakeTableCity

   ```
   Public Function MakeTableCity()
   DoCmd.SetWarnings False
   Dim db As Database
   Set db = Application.CurrentDb
   Dim distinctValues As DAO.Recordset
   Set distinctValues = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT table_name_column FROM SELREP GROUP BY table_name_column", dbOpenSnapshot)
   Do Until distinctValues.EOF
   DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * INTO " & distinctValues("table_name_column") & " FROM SELREP WHERE table_name_column ='" & distinctValues("table_name_column") & "'"
   distinctValues.MoveNext
   Loop
   DoCmd.SetWarnings True
   Set distinctValues = Nothing
   Set db = Nothing
   End Function
   ```

Comment: Why do you need a separate table for every city?  MySQL is built to handle having multiple cities' data together in a single table.

Comment: Indeed, having multiple identically-structured tables is a strong sign of a bad design.  It is also a form of denormalization.

Comment: So users of a particular city can easily navigate to their own city data.

Comment: Although you can partition by city, you will have fairly unbalanced partitions most likely. (e.g. Portland, OR would most likely have less data than New York, NY)

Comment: Just use a WHERE clause to filter results by city name

Comment: I see a table `city` with data about cities as fairly **good normalization**, not the opposite.

Comment: If, on the other hand, the OP means to create a new table for every city then it's **very bad** denormalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you are planning to create a new
  table city with data about cities,
  meaning one row for every city, then
  go ahead and read the answer.
- If , on the other hand, you are
  planning to make a new table for
  every city, with identical columns,
  then your plan is very bad design.
  Read about normalization first.

---

First alternative is to create a table named `city` with fields that you want. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE city
( id INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY
, name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
, population INT
, state CHAR(2)
) ;
```

Then copy the different city names into it with:

```
INSERT INTO city (name)
  ( SELECT DINSTINCT city     --- change "city" into REPLACE(city, ' ', '_')
    FROM table_A              --- for the small changes you want 
  ) ;
```

Then, update the other fields (population, state, etc).

If no two cities have same name, the `JOIN`s between the two tables can then be done using `ON table_A.city = city.name`

If not, (and better anyway as the `Primary Key` of `city` will be smaller), you may `ALTER` the structure of `table table_A` by adding a field `cityid` and dropping the `city` field. Then the `JOIN`s between the two tables will be done using `ON table_A.cityid = city.id`

---

Second option is to directly create table city with:

```
CREATE TABLE city AS
  ( SELECT DINSTINCT city AS name  --- change "city" into REPLACE(city, ' ', '_')
    FROM table_A                   --- for the small changes you want 
  ) ;
```

and then alter the table defining Primary Key, adding (population, state, etc).